# Printing to a printer attached to a network USB hub

Tags: usb, printing, networking

I have [this device](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=105&cp_id=10521&cs_id=1052103&p_id=8081&seq=1&format=2).  It is connected to my router and allows the Windows PCs in my house to use printers, USB speakers, external HDs, etc... that are plugged into it as though they were plugged into local USB ports.

The software that came with the device does not work under Linux.

Is there any other way to get Ubuntu to communicate with this network USB hub and use the devices attached to it?

Answer (score 1):

Your device supports LDP, so you should try adding an LDP printer:

1. start printer (in the system menu)
2. add a new printer (+ symbol)
3. As host, type the IP of your device (eg. 192.168.2.1)
4. As queue, try lpt1

(I'm not so sure about the right english turns, because I run Xubuntu on german)

Good luck! If you got that, maybe you can help me with my ldp problem?: [How can I prevent a LDP Printer from printing a blank page at the end of the job?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85615/how-can-i-prevent-a-ldp-printer-from-printing-a-blank-page-at-the-end-of-the-job)