# How can I prevent a LDP Printer from printing a blank page at the end of the job?

Tags: usb, printing, networking

I have a new router *(Speedport W 921V)* which has USB ports on which I connected my printer *(HP DeskJet 950C)*.

Printing works *(URI: lpd://192.168.2.1/lpt1),* but after each job, the printer sucks out one extra blank page.

How can avoid this extra non printed page?

(I'm using Xubuntu 11.10 and hplip 3.11.7-1ubuntu3. If the printer is connected to the PC directly or via a Windows computer (samba), the problem doesn't occur.)

Comment: Xubuntu 11.10 and hplip 3.11.7-1ubuntu3.


According to https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/OpenPrinting/Database/CupsFAQ#Why_does_a_blank_page_print_for_every_print_job.3F , I also tried to set ps_accounting = 0 in /etc/foomatic/filter.conf, no effect. (/usr/lib/cups/filter/cupsomatic is not a readable file)

Comment: IPP instead of LDP doesn't work at all.

Comment: lpd://192.168.2.1/LPT1_PASSTHRU: same as before, job ends with one blank page   
lpd://192.168.2.1/PASSTHRU: doesn't print, error message: /usr/lib/cups/backend/lpd failed

Comment: when setting up the 950c you have a choice of 6 drivers - does any of the others (i.e. not the recommended driver) work better?

Comment: Does it print without the extra page when you print from the Windows PC to the lpd:// address?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Comment: OK, I bought a new printer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this option at the bottom of `/etc/printcap`

```
:sf:\
```

Comment: No effect. (I did that and restarted cups afterwards with sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart )