# Printing to a printer connected to a wireless router

Tags: networking, usb, printing

I have a [Netgear WNDR4500](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/wirelessrouters/ultimate-performance/WNDR4500.aspx) wireless router which allows me to print wirelessly to a printer connected to it via a USB cable. However, the software used to print to it only works for Windows and OS X.

I've connected a Brother HL-5150D to it. The printer works normally when I connect it directly to the computer, but I don't know how to set it up in Ubuntu when I connect it to the wireless router. I can also connect and print to the printer on a Windows computer using the software provided with the router. I think the software for Windows uses TCP to create a virtual USB bus and the printer is accessed using the same printer installation as when it is plugged directly into the computer.

I don't know what protocol the router uses. I've seen the question [Printing to a printer attached to a network USB hub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57458/printing-to-a-printer-attached-to-a-network-usb-hub), but I'm not sure if my router uses the same protocol. I tried the instructions the answer gave using my router's IP address, but when I try to print a test page it says copying data then says printer is in use. In the printer queue window it says not connected.

I've also tried typing my router's IP address into the "Find Network Printer" section of the add printer dialog, but nothing comes up in the search.

**How can I access a printer connected to the router using Ubuntu?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need go to  /localhost:631/ and follow my step

[image: İmage one]

click "Add Printer"

[image: İmage two]

You will see printer on "Discovered Network Printers:" but i havent .

and manager will help you

NOTE : if answer is true please confirm it . mewbies can forget it

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I get to the "Add Printer" screen my printer isn't listed under "Discovered Network Printers".

Comment: You don't need "Discovered Network Printers". You can choose LPD, type your IP of router (or printer server) and maybe append "queue" (192.168.2.100/queue)

Comment: @uzsolt i know that ip change every restart ?

Comment: I've tried without "queue" and just now with "queue", but it doesn't work. Is LPD the correct protocol for my router?

Comment: @mspencer cant you see your printer in DNP  ?

Comment: @EnesKuray It's possible to add static IP to a client, or not?

Comment: @EnesKuray No I can't.

Comment: @ now , return my answer and write step by step , where is problem ?

Comment: if he use auto-connect , he didnt need static ip but directly ip it doesnt not make sense @uzsolt

Comment: @EnesKuray what do you mean?

Comment: İN MY ANSWER WHERE İS PROBLEM

Comment: @EnesKuray You answer doesn't work - I don't see my printer in the "Discovered Network Printers" section like you said I should.

Comment: @mspencer go 192.168.1.1 and write your printer ip and turn my aswer and select ipp