# how to share a wireless printer in a shared ubuntu/xp lan

Tags: wireless, printing, epson

I have a lan network where a wireless printer is connected.

Ubuntu sees the printer but windows xp does not.

How can I use Ubuntu to share the printer with the xp computers?

Publishing "shared printers connected to to this system" via the right click and share causes the xp machines give me a permission error.   However, if I connect the printer was connected via usb it would work but since it is wirelessly it gives the error.

The steps I have already done are:

1. Share printer through the Printer Server Options and the Sharing option inside the Printing options.
2. Went to the CUPS Website: http://local.host:631 and tried configuring through there.
3. Configured Samba to share the Printer via the smb.cfg.

After doing all the above steps, the XP clients can see the printer but can not connect to it giving me a permission error.

Comment: Thanks virtualxtc but I already did the steps mentioned there. I even have a question answered with a step by step guide on sharing a printer over the network. The problem appears when sharing a wireless printer. Simply sharing the printer does not work. No sharing option, server or printer specific works. Xp still gives a permission error. It sees the printer on ubuntu but it does not work.

Comment: have you tried setting them up as a google cloud printer and then installing them as a cloud printer in windows?

Comment: The printer should not use anything outside the intranet.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221404/printing-to-a-printer-connected-to-a-wireless-router)?

Comment: Hi Mitch and thanks for the comment. Yes I also did that. I have updated the question with all steps I did this week.